# как отдать сайт заказчику? Надо ли будет потом его содержать (сайт)?

Tags: домен, веб-сайт

Когда ты создал сайт ты также должен купить домен для этого сайта. Что стоит денег. Тоесть когда ты отдашь сайт заказчику, то ты навеки вечные обязаешься оплачивать домен для этого сайта? И как ты вообще можешь передать сайт? И даже если ты его передал то о сайте можно будет забыть? Или теперь ты долже не только оплачивать домен, так ещё и поддерживать сайт в рабочем состоянии?

Comment: Без договоренностей вы ничем не обязаны заказчику, можете вообще просто отдать исходники и все

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, при регистрации домена указываются данные заказчика, после чего Вы не будете связаны с этим доменом никак.

Во-вторых, оплачивает услугу тот, кому это нужно. Заказчику же нужен сайт, а не Вам. Вы не обязаны платить за продление домена или хостинга. Если вы не будете платить за них, то хостинг Вам отключат, а домен сможет купить кто-то другой. Только у заказчика интерес к продлению и того и другого.

Самый простой вариант: регистрируете аккаунт у регистратора доменных имен, ищете нужный домен, проверяете занят ли он. Если нет, то просите оплатить заказчика этот домен (у некоторых регистраторов можно выставлять счета, можно выставить счет и попросить заказчика оплатить). То же самое с хостингом. а дальше уже спокойно занимаетесь настройкой.

Заказчику после регистрации домена и хостинга просто передаются доступы и от того, и от другого, а дальше он уже сам занимается фин. вопросами.